# why register() from swiper web component broken my perfomance

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

my problem is that when I try to call register in the TS code, I have an infinite number of component calls. Logically, the component is redrawn when changes are sent to it or to it, but changes do not occur, but instead there are endless calls, therefore, because of this, the site page begins to hang, I track if anything through AngularDevTools.

TS code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
import { catchError, delay, EMPTY, map, of, retry, Subject, switchMap, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs'
import { MessagesErrors } from 'src/app/enums/messages-errors'
import { MessagesAuth } from 'src/app/enums/messages-auth'
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service'
import { EventsService } from 'src/app/services/events.service'
import { ToastService } from 'src/app/services/toast.service'
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'
import { VkService } from 'src/app/services/vk.service'
import { IonicSlides } from '@ionic/angular'
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {register} from 'swiper/element/bundle'
import {Swiper} from 'swiper/types'
import { SightsService } from 'src/app/services/sights.service'
import { CommentsService } from 'src/app/services/comments.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-card',
  templateUrl: './event-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-card.component.scss'],
})
export class EventCardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit  {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private eventsService: EventsService,
    private sightsService: SightsService,
    private commentsServices: CommentsService,
    private toastService: ToastService,
    private vkService: VkService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private sanitizer:DomSanitizer,
  ) { }
  
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>()

  @Input() callFromCabinet: boolean = true
  @Input() event!: any
  @Input() isSight: boolean = false
  comments: boolean = false

  @ViewChild('swiper')
  elementRef?: ElementRef
  viewElement: boolean = false
  viewElementTimeStart: number = 0
  viewElementTimeEnd: number = 0

  swiperRef: ElementRef | undefined
  swiper?: Swiper
  swiperCurrentSlide?: number
  swiperTotalSlids?: number

  swiperModules = [IonicSlides]

  userAuth: boolean = false

  host: string = environment.BACKEND_URL
  port: string = environment.BACKEND_PORT

  favorite: boolean = false
  loadingFavotire: boolean = false

  like: boolean = false
  loadingLike: boolean = false
  startLikesCount: number = 0
  vkLikesCount: number | null = null
  //windowComment: boolean = false

  



  
  ngOnInit() {
    register()
    this.userAuth = this.authService.getAuthState()
    this.startLikesCount = this.event.likes ? this.event.likes.vk_count + this.event.likes.local_count : 0
    this.favorite = this.event.favorites_users_exists! 
    this.like = this.event.liked_users_exists!
    // window.addEventListener('scrollend', this.scrollEvent, true);

    // We throw a request to the VK to update the likes and like us if the user likes in the VK
    if(this.event.vk_group_id && this.event.vk_post_id){
      this.getVkEventLikes(this.event.vk_group_id, this.event.vk_post_id)
      this.isLikedUserVKEvent(this.event.vk_group_id, this.event.vk_post_id)
    }
    
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    register()

    this.swiper = this.swiperRef?.nativeElement.swiper
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.swiperCurrentSlide = this.swiper?.realIndex! + 1
      this.swiperTotalSlids =  this.swiper?.slides.length 
      this.swiper?.autoplay.start()
      ,1000
    }) // Without this crutch, autoplay only works in the first card

    this.swiper?.on('slideChange', () => {
      this.swiperCurrentSlide = this.swiper?.realIndex! + 1
    })
    
    this.cdr.detectChanges()
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<ion-card>
<!-- ['/sights', event.id ] - it was too lazy to redo so here event.id implies the id of the place, since the component is universal and you can pass the place -->
  <div class=" ripple-parent rectangle" >
    <swiper-container 
      [routerLink]="isSight ? ['/sights', event.id] : ['/events', event.id]"
      #swiper
      [modules]="swiperModules" 
      
      autoplay-disableOnInteraction="false"
      [followFinger]="false" 
      [loop]="true" 
      [initialSlide]="0" 
    > 

      <ng-container *ngIf="event.files; else notFiles">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let file of event.files">
          <swiper-slide *ngIf="file.local === 1 && file.file_types[0].name === 'image'">
            <ion-img style="background-image: url('{{host}}:{{port}}{{ file.link }}');"/>
            <img alt="{{file.name}}" src="{{host}}:{{port}}{{ file.link }}" style="z-index: 10;" />
          </swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide *ngIf="file.local === 0 && file.file_types[0].name === 'image'">
              <ion-img  style="background-image: url('{{ file.link }}');"/>
              <img alt="{{file.name}}" src="{{ file.link }}" style="z-index: 10;"/>
          </swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide *ngIf="file.local === 0 && file.file_types[0].name === 'video'">
            <iframe [src]="file.link + '&autoplay=1&mute=1'|safeVideoByUrl" allow="encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture;" autoplay width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
          </swiper-slide>
        </ng-container>
      

</ion-card>
```

i trying delete register but this given broken page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an issue where your Ionic component is stuck in an infinite change detection loop, causing performance issues and hangs.

This can happen when changes within your component trigger further changes that lead to an infinite loop. To debug and resolve this issue, you can perform the following steps:

**Check for unintentional infinite loops**

**Use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush: Consider using the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy for your component**

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyComponent {
  // ...
}
```